# Yii::app()->user->id; gets name of user not ID

Tags: yii

I am trying to get the user id but no luck so far...

`echo Yii::app()->user->id;`

and

`echo Yii::app()->user->getId();`

return the name of user which is weird. 
Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should have getId function in user Identity

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to implement getId() in your identity class. Its explained here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#defining-identity-class

Answer (score 9):

Yii::app()->user returns a component CWebUser by default.

When you want to get some additional information about user, you need to extend this component.

Create a file `WebUser.php` in your `components` folder. (my example below)

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    /**
     * Gets the FullName of user
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->_model->first_name . ' ' .$this->_model->last_name;
    }
}
```

In your config file find section

```
'components'=>array(
'user'=>array(
'class'=>'WebUser'
)
)
```

if there is no this section , just create it. And change 'class'=> to WebUser'.

Comment: why do we use 'components'=>array(
`'user'=>array(
'class'=>'WebUser'
)
)`? For adding extra classes?

Comment: @Riaz for extending CWebUser behaviors

Comment: @RiazKhan: To tell Yii that it should create an instance of your own `WebUser` class (that provides this extra functionality) instead of the built-in `CWebUser`.

Answer (score 2):

Or you are can use `setState`:

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
    private $_id;
    public function authenticate()
    {
        $record=Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('mail'=>$this->username));
        if($record===null)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if($record->password!==md5($this->password."325"))
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else
        {
            $this->_id = $record->id;
            $this->setState('role', $record->active);
            $this->setState('mail', $record->mail);
            $this->setState('name', $record->name);
            $this->setState('surname', $record->surname);
            $this->setState('mobile', $record->mobile);
            $this->setState('adress', $record->adress);
            $record->count_login += 1;
            $record->update();
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}


<?php echo Yii::app()->user->name." ".Yii::app()->user->surname; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use getid function  in the Component/Useridentity to get user id and name etc..

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
    {

            private  $_id;
        public function authenticate()
        {
           $users=Users::model()->find("email_id='$this->username'");                  

           $this->_id=$users->user_id;

        }

        public  function getId(){
            return $this->_id;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display it on a views this should do:

```
echo Yii::$app->user->id;
```